# Request CSRF + Access-Control-Allow-Headers

Tags: python, django, reactjs

Im developing an application with two core. Client Side with ReactJs and a Server Side made with Django.

[image: simple project scheme]

The Client will makes a lot of GET/POST request to the server. To prevent CSRF problem, every Ajax Request has CSRF-TOKEN.

```
beforeSend: function (xhr, settings) {                
          if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
              xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", window.csrftoken);
          }
   [...]
   }
```

This is a piece of the Django/Python view view example of the server:

```
response = HttpResponse(json.dumps(software_settings), content_type="application/json" )
response['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = "*";
response['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = "X-Requested-With, X-Prototype-Version, X-CSRF-Token";
response['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = "POST, GET, OPTIONS";
```

I have two big problems:

FIRST: On online solutions, window.csrftoken variables is usually taken from cookie. I sincerely don't know how to create it. Im using unversal-cookie to read and write cookie with React, but I missing the correct data flow between the two applications. The default values is "null" so the first call has null as CRFT Token;

SECOND: I have a problem with response. As see above, I've tried to put a lot of configurations entry fro Access-Control. This is a piece of request headers:

```
Access-Control-Request-Headers:x-csrftoken
Access-Control-Request-Method:POST
Connection:keep-alive
Host:localhost:8000
Origin:http://localhost:3000
```

This is the error I get:

```
Failed to load http://localhost:8000/get_software_settings/: 
Request header field X-CSRFToken is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

I think Im missing something considering the flow of the application. Consider one last thing:
*In production, the reactjs app will be compiled to be put in the same server as django application (apache).*

Thanks you for any advice.

Comment: check this package https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django generate and serve the CSRFToken [Django CSRF protection](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/csrf/), react take it and pass it when make the POST request, usually a form submit.

So if you want to follow this solution make the first request from react to django to generate the CSRFToken and consume it in the view.

However i have a similar development context and i use Django Rest Framework without CSRFToken, make a normal login in django and in every call from react to Django i pass the session cookies (using the withCredencial parameter) to check if the user is authenticated.